# Finding the area under the curve $y=3-3\cos(t),x=3t-3\sin(t)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, greens-theorem

I need to find the area under the curve $\color{blue}{y=3-3\cos(t),x=3t-3\sin(t)}$ and between $\color{blue}{x=2\pi,x=0\text{,  above axis}}$ using $\color{blue}{\text{Green's theorem}}$.

**My attempt**

I thought to extract $\color{blue}t$ from $y=3-3\cos(t)$ and then to place $\color{blue}t$ here:  $x=3t-3\sin(t)$

$$y-3=-3\cos t$$

$$\frac{y-3}{-3}=\cos t$$

$$\Longrightarrow$$

$$t=\arccos\left(\frac{y-3}{-3}\right)$$

$$x=3\left[\arccos\left(\frac{y-3}{-3}\right)\right]-3\sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac{y-3}{-3}\right)\right)$$

but now it looks weird.

> Is my approach correct?

**Edit:**

this is cycloid https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid[image]

Comment: I don't see the Green's theorem anywhere in your solution. You don't really need explicit $y(x)$ equation to apply it.

Comment: Because I did not finished, I wanted to know if I am in the right diraction

Comment: I think the right track is Area -> 2D integral -[Green's theorem]-> Contour integral -[Parametric equation of the curve]-> Integral by $t$.

Comment: Are you sure the value $x=2\pi$ is correct?

Comment: Yes $x=2\pi,x=0$

Comment: It could be helpful to read about the [cycloid curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid).

Comment: @mickep This is very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no point trying to render this into Cartesian form: it is better to stick to parametric form

Hint...if you can find the right $t$ values for the limits, you only need $$\int y\frac{dx}{dt}dt$$

Comment: @hardmath.."the OP is explicitly asking for something other than a hint" you say, but where does the OP say this?