# Finding the area under the cycloid $x=t-\sin (t),\;y=1-cos (t)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> I need to find the area under the cycloid $x=t-\sin (t),\;y=1-cos (t)$ above axis and between $x=0,x=2\pi$ using $\underline{\text{Green's theorem}}$

**I found in Wikipedia this evaluation:**
$$\begin{align}
&x=r(1-\sin t)\\
&y=r(1-\cos t)\\
&\text{with}\;\frac{dx}{dt}=r(1-\cos t)\\
&0\leq t\leq 2\pi\\
&\text{Since}\;\frac{dx}{dt}=r(1-\cos t)\\
&\text{the area under the arch is:}\\
&A = \int_{t=0}^{t=2 \pi} y \, dx = \int_{t=0}^{t=2 \pi} r^2(1 - \cos t)^2 dt \\
    &= \left. r^2 \left(\frac{3}{2}t - 2\sin t + \frac{1}{2} \cos t \sin t\right) \right|_{t=0}^{t=2\pi} \\
    &= 3 \pi r^2.
\end{align}$$

[image]

Same quastion, with diffrente raduis and with no answer:
[Finding the area under the curve $y=3-3\cos(t),x=3t-3\sin(t)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378402/finding-the-area-under-the-curve-y-3-3-cost-x-3t-3-sint)

> 1)How can I evaluate this using Green's theorem?
>
> 2) I did not understood Wiki's proof, What the meaning of t?

Comment: You've made the question a whole lot easier, compared to your previous version of this question, by changing the limits from $x=3\pi$ to $x=2\pi$ Please see my previous comments

Comment: @DavidQuinn please can you show me how?, I think that in the previous question there was a problem

Comment: My proof is exactly the same as the one you have posted from Wikipedia, but is there something about that proof you are having a problem with?

Comment: @DavidQuinn I will be very heppy to see a full proof

Comment: Hmm...I don't understand what the problem is...are there some steps in it you don't understand? It would take me a while to type it all out :)

Comment: @DavidQuinn that is ok I think the I solved it, thank's anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D$ be an region under cycloid (which are you are finding). So, you should compute an integral:

$$\iint_{D} 1  \; dx dy$$

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) we can find Green's theorem, so if we choose  for example $M(x,y)=2x$ and $L(x,y)=y$ we have:

$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=2-1=1$$

So:

$$\iint_{D}\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\;dxdy=\iint 1\; dx dy$$

By Green's theorem:

$$\iint_{D}\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\;dxdy=\oint_{C} M \; dx+ L\; dy$$

where $M,L$ are like above. $C$ is curve around $D$. Let's find form of $C$: there are two parts: segment and cycloid. Now we should find two points where cycloid touch $y$ axis, that means solution of:

$$y=0=1-\cos(t)$$

so $t=0$ and $t=2\pi$. Putting value of $t$ into second equation we have:

$$x=t-\sin t=0-0=0$$

and

$$x=2\pi-\sin(2\pi)=2\pi$$

So: $C=[0,2\pi] \cup $ arc of cycloid. So it is sufficient to compute integral:

$$\oint_{C} M \; dx+ L\; dy$$

along $C$. Can you finish this solution?